# Is there a specific name for a coffee made with cold heavy cream and a double shot of espresso?

Tags: coffee-culture

Many years ago a friend turned me onto a coffee drink basically a coffee cup filled with (cold) heavy cream, leaving enough room for a double shot of espresso. Stir twice. That's it.

He called it 'life changing' (which it is) but I'd like to know if there is a universal name for it because I usually have to instruct baristas how to make it.

Comment: Not an answer, but I never heard of it.

Comment: Nor have I.  The most similar I know, in having espresso on top of a cold cream layer, is "doppio con panna upside down", but that is espresso shots on top of whipped cream.

Comment: I've been at this a long time in a lot of places, and I'm fairly certain there is no such drink--or, at least, not any traditional drink that fits this description. I've heard this concept called an affogato, an upside down affogato, a doppio con panna, a doppio con leche, and, at one old time favorite shop of mine, a doppio upside down. None of these names accurately describe what the drink is, and I've never come across two places that serve this drink that have called it the same thing.